# watch hook multiple variable in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I using Vuejs and have some variable for filter.

```
data() {
    return {
      startDate: new Date(),
      startTime: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      endTime: new Date(),
      step: 0
    }
}
```

I want watch status of variable above, when change to send request get new Data
I using:

```
watch: {
    startDate() {
      this.filterChange()
    },
    startTime() {
      this.filterChange()
    },
    endDate() {
      this.filterChange()
    },
    endTime() {
      this.filterChange()
    },
    step() {
      this.filterChange()
    }
  }
```

But syntax too long. When i have more variable it same

```
...varibale() { this.filterChange() }
```

How to short syntax?? 
Example in react

```
useEffect(()=>{
  ...balabal
},['var1, 'var2'...])
```

Thank you everyone!